# Aspect oriented Programming?

Tags: c#, vb.net, aop

How can we apply attributes to class function using AOP in C#?

**UPDATE: I am slightly not clear in what context AOP should be used? As we can use AOP for logging purpose, security(Authentication), please suggest some other scenarios where we can take benefit of AOP**

**Is AOP can be use to share data among different running threads in application process?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# doesn't have great support for AOP.

There is a framework, [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/), that you may like to look into. It'll probably get you what you want, but it'll never be as good as Java.

-- Edit

If you don't wish you use a Framework like PostSharp, look into the ContextBoundObject class, and also (IIRC), DynamicProxy. But both of these require either a change to your inheritance chain, or a change to the way you instantiate objects.

Comment: hmm..please suggest what is the better approach OOP or AOP in C#?

Comment: Jaswant: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232884/aspect-oriented-programming-vs-object-oriented-programming and any number of others.

Comment: Why will PostSharp never be as good as Java? There is only so much you can do with AOP and PostSharp seems to cabable of doing it all.

Answer (score 5):

AOP is designed to cover what it refers to as cross-cutting concerns, that is functionality that is required by many objects within a system but which is not core to the concerns of those objects. If such requirements are met by coding the cross-cutting concern into objects throughout the system, we end up with a messy, hard-to-maintain implementation split across many objects.

The classic example of a cross-cutting concern is logging: logging is essential to a real, live system and needs to be implemented throughout that system, but is not really a concern of the objects within that system: the *system* may need a sales-tax calculation object to implement logging but logging is not really a concern of the sales-tax calculation object itself. AOP allows us to specify these system-wide (cross-cutting) requirements separately to our main business logic and then weave the two together, either at run-time or compile-time.

AOP works by intercepting calls to methods on objects. The interception points are known as pointcuts and the intercepted method is the advised method, with the code being advised on the intercepted method being known as the advice. I am only familiar with AOP via Spring.Net's AOP Framework which allows you to specify and apply pointcuts and advices both via configuration files and programmatically. Spring.Net AOP has four types of advice: before, after, around and throws which are invoked on interception of an advised method *before* the advised method is invoked, *after* it is invoked, both before and after its invocation and when an exception is thrown respectively. Whether applied via configuration or programmatically, the *advised* method has no knowledge of Spring.Net AOP or even that it has been advised.

Another example of where AOP is useful is transactions. If we try and implement this in code within objects we end up with objects that have to be aware that they are acting within a transaction which is, to my mind, not a desirable design feature. AOP allows us to create and co-ordinate transactions externally to the objects taking part in the transaction, which can give a much more stable, maintainance-friendly design.

The Spring.Net documentation is very good at explaining AOP in general and Spring.Net's implementation of AOP in particular and contains many examples. It is well worth a look even if you are not considering using the Spring.Net AOP framework.