# AOP Fundamentals

Tags: aop

Aspect-oriented programming is a subject matter that has been very difficult for me to find any good information on.  My old Software Engineering textbook only mentions it briefly (and vaguely), and the wikipedia and various other tutorials/articles I've been able to find on it give ultra-academic, highly-abstracted definitions of just what it is, how to use it, and when to use it. Definitions I just don't seem to understand.

My (very poor) understanding of AOP is that there are many aspects of producing a high-quality software system that don't fit neatly into a nice little cohesive package. Some classes, such as Loggers, Validators, DatabaseQueries, etc., will be used all over your codebase and thus will be highly-coupled.  My (again, **very** poor) understanding of AOP is that it is concerned with the best practices of how to handle these types of "universally-coupled" packages.

**Question :** Is this true, or am I totally off? If I'm completely wrong, can someone please give a concise, laymen explanation for what AOP is, an example of a so-called *aspect*, and perhaps even provide a simple code example?

Comment: nice question also  nicely questioned.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Separation of Concerns is a fundamental principle in software development, there is a classic paper by David Parnas [On the Criteria To Be Used in Decomposing Systems into Modules](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Design/criteria.pdf) that may introduce you to the subject and also read [Uncle Bob's SOLID Principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod).

But then there are Cross Cutting concerns that might be included in many use cases like authentication, authorization, validation, logging, transaction handling, exception handling, caching, etc that spawn all the layers in software. And if you want to tackle the problem without duplication and employing the DRY principle, you  must handle it in a sophisticated way.

You must use declarative programming, that simply in .net could be annotating a method or a property by an attribute and what happened later is changing the behavior of code in runtime depending of those annotations.

You can find a nice chapter on this topic in [Sommerville's Software engineering book](http://www.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~ifs/Books/SE9/SampleChapters/PDF/Chap21-AOSD.pdf)

Useful links
[C2 wiki CrossCuttingConcern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CrossCuttingConcern), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658105.aspx), [How to Address Crosscutting Concerns in Aspect Oriented Software Development](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=375541)

Comment: Jani - thank you for the helpful response and links. It will take me some time to "digest" them, but I'm sure I'll have more educated questions after the weekend. I'll consider this question answered for now, because subsequent questions will be more specific. Thanks again!

Comment: well explanatory example for understanding AOP here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232884/aspect-oriented-programming-vs-object-oriented-programming/232918#232918

Answer (score 2):

AOP is a technique where we extract and remove the cross cutting concerns (logging, Exception handling, ....) from our code into it’s own aspect. leaving our original code focusing only on the business logic. not only this makes our code more readable, maintainable but also the code is DRY.

This can be better explained by an example:

[Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) in the .net world using Castle Windsor](http://astrocoder.com/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-in-the-net-world-using-castle-windsor/)
or 
[Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) in the .net world using Unity](http://astrocoder.com/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-in-the-net-world-using-unity/)

Answer (score 0):

AOP is about crosscutting concerns i.e. things that you need to do throughout the whole application. For instance logging. Suppose you want to trace when you enter and exit a method. This is very easy with aspects. You basically specify a "handler" for an event, such as entering a method. If necessary you can also specify with "wildcards" which methods you are interested in and then it is just a matter of writing the handler code, that could for instance log some info.

Answer (score 0):

Aspect Oriented Programming  is basically for separating the cross-cutting concerns (Non-functional) and develop it as aspects, like, security, logging, monitor etc., kept it  aside whenever you need in your application, you can use it as plug & play. Only benefit we can achieve is clean code ,less code and programmers can focus on business logic(core concerns) , so that better modularity and quality system can be developed.