# How can I put key with null value in net.sf.json.JSONObject?

Tags: java, json

I am using **net.sf.json.JSONObject**. It will remove `key` if my value is **null** while I am trying to put data in Json object using [put](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html#put%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) method.

Is there any way to keep my **key** as it is in my object even my value is null?

for ex.

`JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 json.put("myKey",null);`

Then my output is : `{}`

But I want

output : `{"myKey",""}`

How can I do?

Answer (score 7):

```
json.put("myKeyu",JSONObject.NULL);
```

More details [here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Hi..it is n't possible in my case..my value is coming dynamically from database. So it may be null or not.

Comment: why not to do this: json.put("myKeyu",value == null?JSONObject.NULL:value);

Comment: yes you are right..we can do but I already developed my application and I want some global solution by which I have to change at only one place..in your case whenever I put value in json, I have to do change..can't it be possible by some JsonConfig?

Comment: No. I doubt it's possible to do through JsonConfig. I think you can try using AOP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829088/java-aspect-oriented-programming-with-annotations and intercept all JSONObject.put methods and replace your null with JSONObject.NULL.

Answer (score 1):

`JSONObject.NULL` is for Apache Commons JSONObject.

Try the following instead:

```java
json.put("key", JSONNull.getInstance())
```

Here follows the documentation for `net.sf.json.JSONObject`:
http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html

Search for `JSONNull` to find out more.

Answer (score -2):

```
JSONObject backJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        backJsonObject.put("111", "NULL");
        backJsonObject.put("111", "null");  how to output {"111":"null"} instead of  {"111":null}  in net.sf.json
```

Comment: It will be better if you could explain your answer.