# JSONObject.element() method converts "null" string value to null

Tags: java, json

When I try to put `"null"` string value to a `JSONObject` using the API `JSONObject.element(key, value)`, this API converts this `"null"` string value to `null`.

API used: net.sf.json.JSONObject, 
JAR version: json-lib-2.3-jdk15

```java
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
jObj.element("msg", null);
```

For the given code snippet, the output is

```
{"msg":null}
```

However, it should be

```
{"msg":"null"}
```

Comment: You don't use a string null in your code

Comment: For some reason, the null string as typed by the user is passed from the UI, this is being validated and sent back to the browser as a JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I put key with null value in net.sf.json.JSONObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932188/how-can-i-put-key-with-null-value-in-net-sf-json-jsonobject)

Comment: Nope, that is related to putting null key, this is related to "null" value

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I have handled this at the UI side. The JSONObject API doesn't support the requirement.