# What are the differences between Aspect-oriented programming and object-oriented programming

Tags: oop, aop

The question is self-explanatory. What are the differences between these two?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aspect Oriented Programming  vs. Object-Oriented Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232884/aspect-oriented-programming-vs-object-oriented-programming)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aspect Oriented Programming vs. Object-Oriented Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232884/aspect-oriented-programming-vs-object-oriented-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is already answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232884/aspect-oriented-programming-vs-object-oriented-programming)

Answer (score 2):

OOP builds a program up. AOP cuts across it.

I wouldn't say they're different as in alternatives really, more that AOP is a facet of OOP.