# How to use AOP with AspectJ for logging?

Tags: java, logging, aop, aspectj

I would like to add "trace" messages to all my public methods as follows:

```
public void foo(s:String, n:int) { // log is a log4j logger or any other library
  log.trace(String.format("Enter foo with s: %s, n: %d", s, n))
  ...
  log.trace("Exit foo") 
}
```

Now I would like to add all those `log.trace` to my methods automatically with AOP (and byte code instrumentation). I am thinking about `AspectJ`. Does it make sense? Do you know any open-source, which does exactly that?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. AspectJ is open source, as is Javaassist.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have created a simple aspect to capture the execution of public methods. The core of this AspectJ code is the pointcut definition:

```
pointcut publicMethodExecuted(): execution(public * *(..));
```

Here we are capturing all public methods with any return type, on any package and any class, with any number of parameters.

The advice execution could be visualized on code snippet below:

```
after(): publicMethodExecuted() {
    System.out.printf("Enters on method: %s. \n", thisJoinPoint.getSignature());

    Object[] arguments = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
    for (int i =0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        Object argument = arguments[i];
        if (argument != null){
            System.out.printf("With argument of type %s and value %s. \n", argument.getClass().toString(), argument);
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("Exits method: %s. \n", thisJoinPoint.getSignature());
}
```

This advice use **thisJoinPoint** to get the method signature and arguments. And that's it. Here is the aspect code:

```
public aspect LogAspect {

pointcut publicMethodExecuted(): execution(public * *(..));

after(): publicMethodExecuted() {
    System.out.printf("Enters on method: %s. \n", thisJoinPoint.getSignature());

    Object[] arguments = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
    for (int i =0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        Object argument = arguments[i];
        if (argument != null){
            System.out.printf("With argument of type %s and value %s. \n", argument.getClass().toString(), argument);
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Exits method: %s. \n", thisJoinPoint.getSignature());
}
```

For more complex examples I would recommend the book [AspectJ: In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1930110936).

Comment: Beware of the `System.out`, you really should use a logging framework facade such as SLF4J

Answer (score 31):

[`@Loggable`](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-loggable.html) annotation and an AspectJ aspect from [jcabi-aspects](http://aspects.jcabi.com/) is a ready mechanism for you (I'm a developer):

```
@Loggable(Loggable.DEBUG)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

To log both entry and exit, as per the question's requirements:

```
@Loggable(Loggable.DEBUG, prepend=true)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

All logs go to SLF4J. Check [this post](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html) for more details.

Comment: @DaveJarvis this particular code will only log the exit, to log both you will need `@Loggable(prepend=true)`, see http://aspects.jcabi.com/apidocs-0.22.5/com/jcabi/aspects/Loggable.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use different pointcuts to make your requirement. This [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html) will help you.

Straight [forward solution](http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/logging-with-aspectj/)

Comment: This is just like another documentation. Not a crisp solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this open source http://code.google.com/p/perfspy/. PerfSpy is a runtime logging, performance monitoring and code inspecting tool. It uses ApsectJ to weave around your application code at runtime, and logs the execution time of every method and its input parameters and values. It has a UI application, in which you can view the method invocations and their input and return values as trees. With it, you can spot performance bottlenecks and understand complex code flow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my simple implementation to log entering , exiting and log Exceptions from methods

Annotation

```
package test;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface Audit {

}
```

Interceptor

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;


@Aspect
public class ExceptionInterceptor {

    private static final java.util.logging.Logger LOGGER = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExceptionInterceptor.class.getName());

    @Around("execution(* * (..))"
            + " && @annotation(test.Audit)"
    )
    public Object intercept(final ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        final Method method
                = MethodSignature.class.cast(point.getSignature()).getMethod();
        String mName = method.getName();
        String cName = method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Entering {0}:{1}", new Object[]{cName, mName});
        Object out = null;
        try {
            out = point.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logExceptions(t, point);
        }
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Exiting {0}:{1}", new Object[]{cName, mName});
        return out;
    }

    private void logExceptions(Throwable t, final ProceedingJoinPoint point) {
        final Method method
                = MethodSignature.class.cast(point.getSignature()).getMethod();
        String mName = method.getName();
        String cName = method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
        Object[] params = point.getArgs();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Exception caught for [");
        sb.append(cName);
        sb.append(".");
        sb.append(mName);
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            Object param = params[i];

            sb.append("\n");
            sb.append("  [Arg=").append(i);
            if (param != null) {
                String type = param.getClass().getSimpleName();

                sb.append(", ").append(type);

                // Handle Object Array (Policy Override)
                if (param instanceof Object[]) {
                    sb.append("=").append(Arrays.toString((Object[]) param));
                } else {
                    sb.append("=").append(param.toString());
                }
            } else {
                sb.append(", null");
            }
            sb.append("]");
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, sb.toString(), t);

    }
}
```

How to use it

```
@Audit  
public void testMethod(Int a,int b, String c){
}
```

Maven dependencies 
Compile

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Weaving

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>ajc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I used your exact code and project setup, but the interceptor is never called. Any help?

Comment: Why have you written the code for advice yourself while you are also using the library?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `-javaagent:<path o>aspectjweaver-1.8.7.jar` to your arguments in run configurations.