# Log enter and exit of function flow in Java

Tags: java, logging

I'm new to Java, I have to log enter and exit of function flow, it's quite easy doing it in C++, but I don't know how to do it in Java.
Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Thie topic is really wide, you can google about Instrumentation of Java code.

Comment: How did you do it in C++? What have you tried in Java? Are you familiar with aspects - which is probably what you should try.

Comment: Have a look at [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/), it might help.

Comment: IMHO. It's easier in Java than C++ and you can weave additional code at build time or runtime. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839077/how-to-use-aop-with-aspectj-for-logging

Answer (score 2):

There are several logging libraries (log4J http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/ being a commonly used one) and slf4J http://www.slf4j.org/ being particularly useful as it is library agnostic.

If you want to log every function entry/exit you could look at AspectJ/AOP as mentioned in this post [How to use AOP with AspectJ for logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839077/how-to-use-aop-with-aspectj-for-logging)