# Make every method that runs (in a class) print out that it's running in a log file

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2013

I often have to analyze (semi)complex software systems to add a small feature or tweak something in the code. To better grasp the flow of the code, I like to have a temporary flowchart to show me the flow of (a part of the) code. For example:

-User clicks on button Start
-Method "button_pressed_start" runs
-Method "do something" runs
-The calculatued value of "do something" was : 42 (sometimes I like additional info)
-Method "show_result" runs

Using a stacktrace doesn't work because what I need is the CHANGES to the stacktrace, not the stacktrace itself. The way I do this is now by adding a sysout statement in every method in Eclipse, or a Debug.Writeline statement in Visual studio. Of course, this is cumbersome and it does not really show if  method A invokes method B.

Are their any programs, tools or practices to accomplish this? My main IDE's are Eclipse and Visual Studio.

Comment: You could use `AspectJ` for Eclipse - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839077/how-to-use-aop-with-aspectj-for-logging

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse there are a few plugins that I found for you to use:

[Control Flow Graph Factory 4.3.1](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/control-flow-graph-factory#.UrK_eWRdVD4) and [Sourcecode Visualizer 4.3.2](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sourcecode-visualizer#.UrK_eGRdVD4) both look like good tools for analysing what is going on in your program. As for auto inserting a print statement, I'm afraid I don't know of any way to do that. Unless you feel like writing a regular expression and parsing your java files.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET applications you can use the [Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to show all executed methods with parameters and return values.