# How can I track the number of calls to a method in JDK?

Tags: java, performance

I want to find a way to track the number of calls to a slow JDK method like `UUID#randomUUID` and see how many times it actually get called, how much time is actually spent on this function, etc.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250303/java-application-profiling

Comment: I suggest using a profiler to see where the most CPU time is spent.