# Inserting logging at the start and end of function painlessly in java

Tags: java

So the problem is this:
I want to add logging so that we can track when a function starts executing, and when the function is done executing.

I suppose I could try and make Eclipse insert the logging calls at the start and end of a function, but because not everyone uses Eclipses, that didn't seem to be a great idea.

In Python, what I could've done is to write a decorator that takes *args and **kwargs, and either wrap them manually, or wrap all of them via inspection; or if i'm super lazy, I coupdl probably mess with `__call__()` to do what I need,

However, we're now working with java, and all the examples that I've seen requires me to declare an interface, which doesn't seem to be a good solution...

Any suggestions from java experts here?

Comment: Look at [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) or log4j for logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) which uses Aspect Orientation to insert other code before/after your code.

There's an example code in the answer to this question: [How to use AOP with AspectJ for logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839077/how-to-use-aop-with-aspectj-for-logging)