# How to get logs from a .jar file?

Tags: java, logging, jar

I have an **abc.jar** file and it has some Java classes in it. I don't have the source code of it. I want to get logs of the classes/methods that's been hit while debugging.How can I do that?

P.S - I could have used **log4j** for it but I don't have the source code.

Comment: Do you know whether your `abc.JAR` file uses `slf4j` ?

Comment: No, that abc.jar does not use/implement any logging framework.

Comment: try running your jar on command line.

Comment: Can you post the manifest?

Comment: `java -jar abc.jar >out.txt 2>err.txt` will capture standard output and error to two separate files.

Comment: I think you should be able to use AOP/aspectJ to dynamically add logging to the classes in the jar. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839077/how-to-use-aop-with-aspectj-for-logging

Comment: If it doesn't use any logging framework how can you possibly get logs out of it? Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say if you have abc.jar and it doesn't use any framework for logging, and you don't have any source code as you have mentioned. No, you can't get logs this way.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a profiling tools such as [Java's hprof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html%20Java's%20hprof). It is a good introduction to profiling. While not powerful, it is a good start. There are plenty of other useful profiling tools. Just google them.

For hprof, the modes of CPU Usage Sampling Profiles (cpu=samples)

```
e.g. javac -J-agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples Hello.java
```

and CPU Usage Times Profile (cpu=times)

```
e.g. javac -J-agentlib:hprof=cpu=times Hello.java
```

sound like what you needs. They can tell you what is called and how often. What they won't tell you is the state of variables. This is what debugging is used for given that logging is not an option.

Answer (score 4):

You state in your comment that you know that `abc.jar` doesn't use any logging framework.

In that case, it is impossible to get logs from it.

However, what you can do is use a debugger. All IDEs have debuggers. This can help you know the state of the classes being called when you use them.