# Create log method to log parameters and their values on current executing method in java

Tags: java, logging

I want to have method - for example `LogUtil.logCurrentMethod()`, which return parameters of method from which it is executed and their values. 
For example :

```
public void temp(int first, String second, int third){
    LogUtil.logCurrentMethod()
   //something
}
```

and when I call :

```
temp(1, "2", 3);
```

to print:

```
first: 1
second: 2
third: 3
```

I want that, because it is really annoying to log all parameters of methods with 5 parameters for example. `logCurrentMethod` can take parameters, the idea is to make logging easier. Another problem is that when I copy paste Log lines, I often don't change parameters names (so I have for example logged width and width instead of width and height or something like that). I can create `new Object{}.getClass.getEnclosingMethod()` to get this method and to pass it to the method (and use `Reflection` to take their names), but I don't know the values. Other approach is to pass parameters to log method and pass `new Object{}.getClass.getEnclosingMethod()`, but I think there should be an easier and more convenient way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by two ways-

1. By Using Interceptor-[Logging With Interceptors](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-ejb-interceptors-tutorial-and-example)

   Also refer this-[Oracle Doc For Interceptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkigq.html)
2. By Using AspectJ- [Logging With AspectJ](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html)

   Refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839077/how-to-use-aop-with-aspectj-for-logging) to know how to use AspectJ for logging purpose.