# Migrating a Java project to AspectJ (Eclipse AJDT)

Tags: java, eclipse, aop, aspectj, ajdt

I'm working on a Java 1.8 project with several modules and one huge cross-cutting concern - *logs* are present in almost every class, in every module. I recently read about Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) and I though it would be nice to use *AspectJ* to make things more modular, just like [the guy from this post did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839077/how-to-use-aop-with-aspectj-for-logging). I decided to give it a try...

Since I'm using *Eclipse Oxygen* and it isn't compatible with the latest [*AJDT*](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/), I've downloaded *Eclipse Kepler* and the latest [*AJDT*](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/). However, I've noticed that once *AJDT* was installed, all Java Compiller's settings were set to *J2SE-1.4*, and I couldn't put it back to *1.8*, since this option was not available anymore on the IDE. This caused me a lot of compiler's errors, such as:

```
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
```

and

```
'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
```

I have the feeling that *AJDT* is outdated and incompatible with the latest java versions. However, since this is the first time I'm trying to use *AOP*, I wonder if I'm not following the correct path...

So, to make it simple and direct, my question is - is it possible to use *AJDT* with *Java 1.8* (maybe manually (directly on a text file) editting some workspace configuration instead of using the IDE's UI, or something like that)? Or, to use *AJDT*, I'll need to make my project compatible with older Java versions, by "fixing", for instance, the `<>` operators, among several other things adopted by the latest versions of Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJDT has a development build for Eclipse Oxygen (4.7), see https://eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/

> AJDT dev builds for Eclipse 4.7
>
> Update Site URL:http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/47/dev/update

I just created a HelloWorld test project with aspects in Oxygen, and it runs under Java 8.