# Delete whitespaces from property in ASP.NET Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, model, whitespace

My application is huge and after one year we've found that customers "like" inserting whitespaces in their names or surnames... Is there any simple way to remove whitespaces from those strings (and not searching for every line in program) or I have to search my whole code and change every line which sets `Osoba`? Wanted to do `set { Osoba = value.Trim(): }` but I also had to assign `get` which I can't do in model's property.

```
public class Event
    {
        [Key]
        public int EventID { get; set; }

        public DateTime AddTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime Start { get; set; }

        public DateTime End { get; set; }

        public EventCreateType EventCreateType { get; set; }

        public EventStatus Status { get; set; }

        public string Osoba { get; set; }

        (...)
    }
```

Comment: Use `String.Trim()` inside the http post action method which handles the form submit and save the trimmed data to database

Comment: That's the point, but what if there are 100 http post actions? Is there any simple way?

Comment: Write  helper methods for each of them. For example : Each view model may have a method called `TrimValues()` which trims it's property values.

Comment: You wants to change the old data or the new data which is going to be inserted in db?

Comment: New data. Old ones I've already replaced.

Comment: Maybe you could implement it as a setter? I don't know if that would work though.

Comment: @TJ Wolschon I can't. If i set a setter, then I have to set a getter. This can't be set in same property without referencing to another property.

Comment: `get { return this.Osoba; } set { this.Osoba = value.Trim(); }`

Comment: @TJ Wolschon heh, no, that can't be implemented. I will get `System.StackOverflowException` due to endless getting `Osoba`

Comment: Bummer, we use that on one of the projects I'm on so I thought it might work.

Comment: Can an Aspect Oriented approach help? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232884/aspect-oriented-programming-vs-object-oriented-programming

Comment: Since it is an asp.net mvc application, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/best-way-to-trim-strings-after-data-entry-should-i-create-a-custom-model-binder; they implemented the trim via a modelbinder, meaning at the moment the posted text gets assigned to the viewmodel.

Comment: @pfx that's what I needed! Thanks!